# Issues after updating to IOS11 and Xcode9!! "com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior", "TIC Read Status"

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ios9

I have updated my phone and Xcode to the most recent update and I am getting tons of warnings.

First one is `2017-09-21 00:23:15.669466+0100 The Kallos[12068:1279021] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57`

and there is literally 2-3 posts about this which doesn't even explain what it is!

This is another warning, I found a similar post which explains this issue but it doesn't give a solution on how to fix it!

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: x, TID: x, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   The Kallos                          0x0000000105d1e4f4 GMSIsApplicationInBackground + 53
5   The Kallos                          0x0000000105d0c74a -[GMSForegroundDispatchQueue initWithName:targetQueue:] + 269
6   The Kallos                          0x0000000105dec5be _ZN7gmscore6vector4text8GlyphSetC2ERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_16TextureAtlasPoolEEEPU28objcproto17OS_dispatch_queue8NSObjectPK8__CTFontff + 344
7   The Kallos                          0x0000000105deba28 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text10GlyphCache11GetGlyphSetEPK8__CTFontf + 214
8   The Kallos                          0x0000000105de94de _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEERKNSt3__16vectorItNS9_9allocatorItEEEEPK8__CTFontf + 22
9   The Kallos                          0x0000000105de95e1 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEEPK8__CTLinebf + 207
10  The Kallos                          0x0000000105d412af _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel22PrefetchGlyphsForGroupEPNS0_12GLLabelGroupE + 181
11  The Kallos                          0x0000000105d411d7 _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel14PrefetchGlyphsEv + 33
12  The Kallos                          0x0000000105db01fa _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior23CreatePendingOperationsERKNSt3__13setINS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_7GLLabelEEENS2_4lessIS7_EENS2_9allocatorIS7_EEEESE_SE_NS0_13LabelDrawModeE + 1096
13  The Kallos                          0x0000000105dafb6d _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14RunLabelingJobERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_11LabelingJobEEE + 357
14  The Kallos                          0x0000000105daf9fa ___ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14CommitInternalEPNS_8renderer14EntityRendererE_block_invoke + 22
15  Foundation                          0x00000001094ca948 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010816c2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010820bd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108150c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001081501ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010814fa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
21  Foundation                          0x0000000109484e5e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
22  The Kallos                          0x0000000105deacb5 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 337
23  Foundation                          0x00000001094928ac __NSThread__start__ + 1197
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f73393b _pthread_body + 180
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f733887 _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f73308d thread_start + 13
2017-09-21 00:23:15.827609+0100 The Kallos[12068:1279035] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: x, TID: x, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   The Kallos                          0x0000000105d1e4f4 GMSIsApplicationInBackground + 53
5   The Kallos                          0x0000000105d0c74a -[GMSForegroundDispatchQueue initWithName:targetQueue:] + 269
6   The Kallos                          0x0000000105dec5be _ZN7gmscore6vector4text8GlyphSetC2ERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_16TextureAtlasPoolEEEPU28objcproto17OS_dispatch_queue8NSObjectPK8__CTFontff + 344
7   The Kallos                          0x0000000105deba28 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text10GlyphCache11GetGlyphSetEPK8__CTFontf + 214
8   The Kallos                          0x0000000105de94de _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEERKNSt3__16vectorItNS9_9allocatorItEEEEPK8__CTFontf + 22
9   The Kallos                          0x0000000105de95e1 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEEPK8__CTLinebf + 207
10  The Kallos                          0x0000000105d412af _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel22PrefetchGlyphsForGroupEPNS0_12GLLabelGroupE + 181
11  The Kallos                          0x0000000105d411d7 _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel14PrefetchGlyphsEv + 33
12  The Kallos                          0x0000000105db01fa _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior23CreatePendingOperationsERKNSt3__13setINS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_7GLLabelEEENS2_4lessIS7_EENS2_9allocatorIS7_EEEESE_SE_NS0_13LabelDrawModeE + 1096
13  The Kallos                          0x0000000105dafb6d _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14RunLabelingJobERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_11LabelingJobEEE + 357
14  The Kallos                          0x0000000105daf9fa ___ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14CommitInternalEPNS_8renderer14EntityRendererE_block_invoke + 22
15  Foundation                          0x00000001094ca948 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010816c2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010820bd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108150c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001081501ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010814fa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
21  Foundation                          0x0000000109484e5e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
22  The Kallos                          0x0000000105deacb5 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 337
23  Foundation                          0x00000001094928ac __NSThread__start__ + 1197
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f73393b _pthread_body + 180
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f733887 _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f73308d thread_start + 13
```

Next warning is

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17AA6A5E-FA21-40BF-8123-2CAEE29D4BBE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C3F9016-4605-4DB8-A480-59B95C5E2994/The Kallos.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17AA6A5E-FA21-40BF-8123-2CAEE29D4BBE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C3F9016-4605-4DB8-A480-59B95C5E2994/The Kallos.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17AA6A5E-FA21-40BF-8123-2CAEE29D4BBE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C3F9016-4605-4DB8-A480-59B95C5E2994/The Kallos.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
```

I feel like this is a problem with the GoogleMaps API and not my code but Im not sure about that.

I will be more than happy to provide more information if needed but my project has around 11-12k lines of code so I don't really know what to upload.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue after updating to Xcode9

Comment: Yepp, having this one too.  UI thread is locking up in the simulator.

Comment: Any solution for this issue. I am having this issue both on device and simulator and even forcing the map load on main thread is not helping here

Comment: My project is very small, just map with clusters, and I also started having this issue after update to Xcode9. Also, map itself feels very slow now, at least on the simulator.

Comment: same issue with map init - using `GoogleMaps (2.4.0)` / XCode - `Version 9.0 (9A235)`

Comment: Hopefully Google will update their SDK soon

Comment: Concerning the slowness detected in the iOS 11 simulators, please refer to the open radar issue with Apple:
http://www.openradar.me/33505938

Answer (score 16):

This issue was reported in Google issue tracker as well:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63322270

Google is aware of it and current state of the bug is Accepted, I would expect a fix in the next version of Google Maps SDK library 2.5.0

Feel free to add star in the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.

**UPDATE**

The issue was marked as fixed today (October 24, 2017). The Google rep wrote

> We believe that this issue should be solved in the Maps iOS SDK v2.5 release. If this issue still occurs, please let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will add a star to the bug

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i've use library for change system font and there was a misspelling in name of the font that's way this weird crash appear