# XCode Main Thread Checker: Google Maps SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm getting this compiler warning :

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:
>   -[UIApplication applicationState] PID: 2250, TID: 542348, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name:
>   com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21

Running:

- XCode Version 9.0 (9A235).
- GoogleMaps-2.4.0.

I guess this is a bug..?

Comment: I filed this a few days ago, same issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66433454

Comment: and looks like this is the same issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63322270

Comment: same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333235/issues-after-updating-to-ios11-and-xcode9-com-google-maps-labelingbehavior

Comment: Thanks Brooks. Seems a lot of people are seeing the same thing. BTW are you also noticing that Google Maps for iOS is super slow in the XCode 9 simulators?

Comment: It's very slow, and i've given up profiling the vc's holding it.

Comment: Simulator is basically unusable right now.

Comment: XCode Version 9.1 beta (9B46) seems to have fixed these usability issues although I still get the Thread Checker warning. I guess that is a Google Maps SDK issue.